# Strict generic enum conversion in F#

Tags: generics, enums, f#, inline

I want to write a function with signature `int -> 'TEnum` that will throw an exception in case the target enum don't contain an input value. Here's my first try:

```
let parseEnum<'TEnum when 'TEnum : enum<int>> (value : int) : 'TEnum =
    let enumType = typeof<'TEnum>
    if not <| Enum.IsDefined (enumType, value) then
        raise <| ArgumentException (sprintf "Invalid value of %A: %d" enumType value)

    enum value
```

The compiler shows me the following error message: "error FS0001: The declared type parameter 'TEnum' cannot be used here since the type parameter cannot be resolved at compile time" (I think that's because of the `enum` function that have an additional constraint).

Well, okay then, I understand the problem. I'll use [statically resolved type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx). Here's my second try:

```
let inline parseEnum2 (value : int) : ^TEnum =
    let enumType = typeof<^TEnum>
    if not <| Enum.IsDefined (enumType, value) then
        raise <| ArgumentException (sprintf "Invalid value of %A: %d" enumType value)

    enum value
```

But compiler still complains: "error FS3156: Unexpected token '>' or incomplete expression" at the line `typeof<^TEnum>`.

What am I doing wrong? How could I write this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need a space between the 'hat' sign `ˆ` and the `<` like this:

```
let enumType = typeof< ^TEnum>
```

In fact you don't need the hat, you can write:

```
open System
let inline parseEnum2 value : 'TEnum =
    let enumType = typeof<'TEnum>
    if not <| Enum.IsDefined (enumType, value) then
        raise <| ArgumentException (sprintf "Invalid value of %A: %d" enumType value)

    enum value
```

Because the static constraint is inferred automatically in this case, the only place when you really have to write the 'hat' is when writing the static constraint by hand.